# How to import a .dbf file into R?

Tags: r, import, dbf

I am trying to import a .dbf file into R Studio as following:

```
install.packages("foreign")
library(foreign)
dis <- read.dbf("M:\\data\\Pro\\dis.dbf", as.is = F)
View(dis)
```

Please tell me if it is correct. Does the path needs an update ?

Comment: Try using normal slashes instead of backslashes in your path.

Comment: Does it give an error? Or a warning? If so, what is that error or warning?